# Href parsing issue in for loop

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I have a table with the following syntax:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><a href=""></a></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><a href=""></a></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
    ......
</tbody>
```

I am able to extract a link as follows:

```
link = page.css('tbody tr td a')[1]['href']
```

However, when I attempt to do this in a `for` loop, it fails and I receive an error about undefined method '[]':

```
rows = page.css('tbody tr')
$numRows = rows.count
links = Array.new
(0..$numRows-1).each do |i|
  links.push(page.css('tbody tr td a')[i]['href'])
```

I was able to fix my issue using this code:

```
rows = page.css('tbody tr')
rows.shift
$num_updates = rows.count
puts rows.count

links = Array.new
page.css('tbody tr td a').each do |i|
links.push(i.attr('href'))
end

columns = Hash.new
(0..$num_updates-1).each do |i|
columns[i] = rows[i].text
columns[i] = columns[i].split("\n")
end
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Also your code isn't valid. We need to see code that is syntactically correct. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Using a global like `$numRows` is code smell; Using globals at all without understanding why you should use them strongly suggests you don't understand variable scoping. `numRows` should be `num_rows` as variables in Ruby are snake_case, not camelCase.

Comment: How did you get that HTML? If you used the browser to show you the source, then don't do that; Instead, request the HTML using cURL, `wget`, HTTPClient, etc., that let you retrieve the HTML without the browser. Browsers do fixups on the HTML, and often add `tbody` tags, which are not in the original HTML.

Comment: I obtained the html as follows - 

page = Nokogiri::HTML open('https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222')

Comment: That page doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure why the second ' is incorporate into the link. If you remove it, it should take you to the site which contains the table I am parsing.

Comment: There is no second `'`: `page = Nokogiri::HTML open('support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222')
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222`

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` loops on the number of `<td>` tags, but only **ONE** of those tds has an `<a>` in it, so `('tbody tr td a')[1]` doesn't exist.

Comment: The table actually repeats for many rows. So there are several <td> tags that have an <a> in them, but not all. I realize my transcribing for rows included an extra td from debugging, so I've removed that from question.

Comment: There does exist a value for page.css('tbody tr td a')[1]['href'] and so forth since I'm able to print out the values. I just don't know how to push these values via a for loop into an array. Trying to understand Nokogiri/ruby syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Meditate on this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(<<EOT)
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="foo"></a></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="bar"></a></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
EOT

doc.search('a').map(&:to_html)        # => ["<a href=\"foo\"></a>", "<a href=\"bar\"></a>"]
doc.search('a').map{ |n| n['href'] }  # => ["foo", "bar"]

doc.search('a').map{ |n| n['href'] }[1]  # => "bar"
```

or:

```
doc.search('a')[1]['href']               # => "bar"
```